# How to convert a Python generator to async generator?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio, generator

I have a generator function in Python which is IO bound. I'd like to convert it to an async generator, where the generator loop is running in a separate process or thread. For example, loading chunks of data from a socket, where we'd like to load the next chunk while we process the previous. I'm imagining a Queue would be used, where the IO thread is buffering chunks (the yield outputs) for the async generator to pickup. Preferably, I'd like to use the concurrent.futures module to allow flexibility in picking between separate process vs thread. What is the best way to go about this?

```py
import time

def blocking():
    """ plain generator with blocking i/o """
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i # fake result
        i += 1

def consumer():
    for chunk in blocking():
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: The solution will certainly entail moving the IO bound part to another thread or Process, where items will be placed in a Queue as you describe.  But the consumer end is not clear.  Can the consumer benefit from multitasking or not?  Do you want to process two or more messages concurrently, or always one at a time?  Will the overall performance bottleneck be the IO or the consumer?  Depending on your answers, you may not want to use asyncio at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unfortunately, not straightforward.

the optional thing in the snippet bellow is the "task group", but it helps with good-practices:

```
import time

import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor # (or Process*)

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)  # Put this wherever you like, with as many workers as you want.

def blocking_task(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    return i

async def async_gen():
    """ plain generator with blocking i/o """
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        async def taskwrapper(awaitable):
            return await awaitable
        tasks = {tg.create_task(taskwrapper(loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_task, i,))) for i in range(10)}
        while tasks:
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            for task in done:
                yield task.result()
            tasks = pending


async def consumer():
    async for i in async_gen():
        print(i)


asyncio.run(consumer())
```

So, this is when you can separate each item-fetching in a task that can be run in a Threadpool as a distinct task.

If you have just a synchronous stream that you want to keep and just wrap it so it can be consumed in an async loop, if you can run that synch generator in its own thread, that can be done by adding some helper-functions and control-flow things - the snippet bellow might help. The `async_gen` function will take care of starting the generator in another thread and fetch chunks asynchronously:

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue as ThreadingQueue, Empty


import time


def blocking():
    """ plain generator with blocking i/o """
    # this will run in other thread, and produced results
    # are comunicated to the asyncio loop in a queue by the
    # "middleware" helper functions
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i
        i += 1


def _threading_queue_item_ready(semaphore):
    # increase the count of available items in the queue so
    # that it can be read in an async-friendly way:
    semaphore.release()

def _producer_wrapper(gen, loop, queue, semaphore):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for item in gen():
            queue.put(item)
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(_threading_queue_item_ready, semaphore)
    wrapper()

async def async_gen(sync_gen):
    """wrapper for the "generator asynchronization" mechanism"""
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(0)
    queue = ThreadingQueue()
    producer_thread = Thread(target=_producer_wrapper, args=(sync_gen, asyncio.get_running_loop(), queue, semaphore))
    producer_thread.start()
    while True:
        await semaphore.acquire()
        # we only get here when there is at least one item in the queue
        item = queue.get()
        yield item
        # intentionaly do not "release" the semaphore: available item count
        # is increased by the producer code

async def consumer():
    async for chunk in async_gen(blocking):
        print(chunk)


asyncio.run(consumer())
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they meant - I think they still want to run the I/O sequentially, just in an executor.

Comment: Yes, my question was actually for sequential IO; e.g. we are loading chunks of data from a socket, so can't be run as separate tasks. (I've modified the question slightly to make that more clear). Though, this answer is still a useful reference.

Comment: So, your example is not good in that case: what needs to be "transformed to async" is exactly our I/O call, and how to do it will be specific for that call. For the `time.sleep(1)` case, the remedy is to change that for `await asyncio.sleep` - and then, just change `def blocking():` for `async def blocking()`.  In this case, I guess a worker thread can be used for the I/O and signal back to the asyncio loop thread it is got a new chunk (pooling a sync, threading, queue would do, but a mechanism using asyncio synchronization prinitives would be better, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most direct answer to your question is to wrap the generator-iterator created by your generator function 'blocking' with a function or class that spins up a thread to populate a queue, and yields from that queue. Something like the code below, though don't actually use this - it is far too brittle in the face of exceptions, incomplete iteration etc - but it shows what I mean:

```
import threading, queue, time

def thr_gen(iterator):
    q = queue.Queue()
    def enqueue():
        for i in iterator:
            q.put(i)
        q.put(StopIteration)
    thr = threading.Thread(target=enqueue, daemon=True)
    thr.start()
    yield from iter(q.get, StopIteration)

def blocking():
    """ plain generator with blocking i/o """
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i # fake result
        i += 1

def consumer():
    for chunk in thr_gen(blocking()):
        print(chunk)
```

If you build out a solution along these lines you need to stick in try/finally blocks, consider what happens to the thread if consumption is incomplete, probably make it a daemon thread etc. I wrote a solution for myself which I have stuck [here](https://gist.github.com/monkeytruffle/36a57792bad4f0c507c6be8111526ec6).

It also includes a decorator class, which you can just bang on any generator function to achieve the same result. (You can then go decorator-crazy to easily see what gains you can get on any of your generator functions!)

As others have said, the question arises as to what you do with the results of this generator - you could just accept the gains from the thread releasing enough idle microseconds to do whatever processing comes next, or you could chunk up your results and allow a multiprocessing pool to do stuff with them. Of course another I/O bound operation would be a good partner to work alongside this threaded generator, in which case you might benefit from playing with queue size limits.